# Using value of array for another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want the user to select a 'province/state' from the first drop down, then see specified areas in that province/state, but i want to add a "other" in the second dropdown for areas which are not listed, but if the user selects "other", i want the input box to show.

I'm quite new to js and I've run into a small problem which i can't fix. sorry if it's been asked, but i tried finding a similar problem without success. Also i couldn't get this working on jsfiddle, so i apologize for the long post.

Most of the options are disabled (still a work in progress)

I have a working example of what i want to do here:

Please look at the snippet.

```js
function filterDropDownLists(provinces, cityfilter) {
        var city1= new Array('Please Select Area','Example 1', 'Example 2', 'Example 3');
        
/*values for second dropdown*/

/*if one of these optios are selected, display specified array above*/
        switch (provinces.value) {
            case 'Gauteng':
                cityfilter.options.length = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < city1.length; i++) {
                    createOption(cityfilter, city1[i], city1[i]);
                }
                break;

            default:
                cityfilter.options.length = 1;                
        }

    }

function createOption(provincefilter, text, value) { /*add the values to the next dropdown */
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = value;
        opt.text = text;
        provincefilter.options.add(opt);
    }
```

```html
<select class="provincefilter" id="provincefilter" onchange="filterDropDownLists(this,document.getElementById('cityfilter'))">
    <option value="selectprovince" selected>Please Select Province</option>  
    <option value="Gauteng">Gauteng</option>

   </select>


   <select class="cityfilter" id="cityfilter"> <!--second dropdown to list specified array-->
    <option value="selectarea" selected>Please Select Area</option>
   
   </select>
```

But the one I'm having a problem with uses an array to to insert the values.
What i want is for the person to select something in the first , then it displays certain values for the second , but for the second  there is an option of 'other', i want to add an input box next to it in case 'other' was selected

problem:

```js
function filterDropDownLists_rblock(provinces, cityfilter) {  
  var gauteng = new Array('Please Select Area','Pretoria East', 'Pretoria North', 'Pretoria Central', 'Johannesburg', 'Midrand', 'Centurion','Other');
        var easterncape = new Array('Please Select Area','Port Elizabeth', 'Durban','Other');
  var freestate = new Array('Please Select Area','Louis Trichardt','Other');
  
  

        switch (provinces.value) {
            case 'Gauteng':
                cityfilter.options.length = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < gauteng.length; i++) {
                    createOption(cityfilter, gauteng[i], gauteng[i]);
                }
                break;
            default:
                cityfilter.options.length = 1;                
        }

    }

function createOption(provincefilter, text, value) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = value;
        opt.text = text;
        provincefilter.options.add(opt);
    }

function city_other_select(otherCitySelect)
{
    if(otherCitySelect){
        otherCityOptionValue = document.getElementById("city_option_other").value;
        if(otherCityOptionValue == otherCitySelect.value){
            document.getElementById("rblock_area_other").style.display = "inline-block";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("rblock_area_other").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("rblock_area_other").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="rblock_business_area"> 
   <select class="rblock_provincefilter" id="rblock_provincefilter" onchange="filterDropDownLists_rblock(this,document.getElementById('rblock_cityfilter'))">
    <option value="selectprovince" selected>Please Select Province</option>  
    <option value="Gauteng">Gauteng</option>
   </select>

   <select class="rblock_cityfilter" id="rblock_cityfilter" onchange="city_other_select(this)">
    <option value="rblock_selectarea" selected>Please Select Area</option>
    <option value="city_option_other" id="city_option_other">Other</option>
   </select>
  
   <div class="rblock_area_other" style="display:none;">
    <input type=text name=areaother size="30px" placeholder="Please specify"/> 
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You have to make the question shorter.
And also you first code box, all the code can be like 10 lines no more.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to edit that part out, it's a placeholder for other areas that i want to add

Comment: you have to make the code more understandable please.

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do and make your code example as short as possible so that it only illustrates your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might get a 'clearer run' at this if you separate your data from your presentation layer and just have the logic work with that. So I've created an object with `province` and `area` properties.

The event handlers then just need to clear, filter and populate the various `<select>` elements.

Give this a try:

```js
var data = [
  {"province": "Gauteng", "area": "Pretoria East"},
  {"province": "Gauteng", "area": "Pretoria North"},
  {"province": "Gauteng", "area": "Pretoria Central"},
  {"province": "Gauteng", "area": "Johannesburg"},
  {"province": "Gauteng", "area": "Midrand"},
  {"province": "Gauteng", "area": "Centurion"},
  {"province": "Sydney", "area": "Surry Hills"},
  {"province": "Sydney", "area": "Redfern"},
  {"province": "Sydney", "area": "Bondi"}
];

$('#provinceFilter').append('<option selected>Please select province</option>');
$('#areaFilter').append('<option selected>Please select area</option>');
$('#otherSelection').hide();

var provinces = [];
$.each(data, function(index, item) {
  if (provinces.indexOf(item.province) < 0) {
    provinces.push(item.province);
  };
});

$.each(provinces, function(index, item) {
  $('#provinceFilter').append('<option value=' + item + '>' + item + '</option>');
});

$('#provinceFilter').on('change', function() {
  $('#areaFilter').empty();
  var areas = [];
  $.each(data, function(index, item) {
    if (areas.indexOf(item.area) < 0 && $('#provinceFilter').val() == item.province) {
      areas.push(item.area);
    };
  });
  $.each(areas, function(index, item) {
    $('#areaFilter').append('<option value=' + item + '>' + item + '</option>'); 
  });
  $('#areaFilter').append('<option value=Other>Other</option>'); 
});

$('#areaFilter').on('change', function() {
  var area = $('#areaFilter').val();
  if (area == 'Other') {
    $('#otherSelection').show();
    $('#otherSelection').val('Which area?');
    $('#otherSelection').focus();
  } else {
    $('#otherSelection').hide();
    $('#otherSelection').val('');  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <select id="provinceFilter">
  </select>
  <select id="areaFilter">
  </select>
  <input id="otherSelection" />
</div>
```

Comment: it works, but it's the same that i get if i don't hide my <input>

Comment: You mean you want to hide the `<input>` as long as `Other` is not the selection for the area filter ?

Comment: yes, i want the user to select 'other' then the input shows up, that's all

Comment: Try it now please - I updated with following `$('#otherSelection').hide();` and `$('#otherSelection').show();` depending on whether the user has selected `Other` in the area filter. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the change event on the `select` and on change check for `other` and show the `input` element.

For that first add an `input` with `hide` as follows,

```
 <input type="text" id="otherInput" name="other" class="hide"/>
```

And add `change` event on select as follows,

```
 cityfilter.addEventListener('change', function(){

        if(cityfilter.value == "other")
        {
          document.getElementById("otherInput").className = "";
        }
    });
```